# Is it possible to filter duplicate records using an XSLT Stylesheet?

Tags: xslt, filtering

Is it possible to filter duplicate records using an XSLT Stylesheet. By that i mean if you get the following code as an input:

```
<payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
</payload>
<payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
</payload>
<payload>
    <name>10</name>
    <date>20</date>
</payload>
<payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
</payload>
```

could it filter the input to produce this output:

```
<payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
</payload>
<payload>
    <name>10</name>
    <date>20</date>
</payload>
```

Comment: The answer is yes, but beyond that it will depend on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Google for "XSLT grouping" (or better still, look it up in the index at the back of your favourite XSLT textbook) and you will find heaps of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an XSLT 1.0 option...

**XSLT 1.0 stylsheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="kPayloads" match="payload" use="concat('N',name,'D',date)"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="payloads">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="payload[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kPayloads', concat('N',name,'D',date)))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input (well-formed)**

```
<payloads>
  <payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
  </payload>
  <payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
  </payload>
  <payload>
    <name>10</name>
    <date>20</date>
  </payload>
  <payload>
    <name>1</name>
    <date>2</date>
  </payload>  
</payloads>
```

**XML Output**

```
<payloads>
   <payload>
      <name>1</name>
      <date>2</date>
   </payload>
   <payload>
      <name>10</name>
      <date>20</date>
   </payload>
</payloads>
```

---

**Edit**

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet will also produce the same output...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="payloads">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="payload" group-by="concat('N',name,'D',date)">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cds="cds_dt" exclude-result-prefixes="cds">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/payload"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/payload">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::payload/name = name)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think that when the OP says "duplicate records", it includes both `<name>` and `<date>` in `<payload>`.